# How Can I Add A Image(s) To My Resources Folder In Xamarin Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day, I Want To Add Different Image To My Resources Folder, Im Using Xamarin.Forms In Visual Studio.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Have you tried right-clicking on the folder yet? There should be a submenu named Add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drop the image on the resources folder in the solution explorer menu